# Custom filtering using AND, OR and NOT

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want custom logic that fetches a value from a read-only database based on answers to questions. The questions and potential answers are known before a query is send and the structure is not decided and part of this question. The problem is there exist `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` cases in the logic (a certain result might be returned if the answer to a question is `NOT` a given value).

Where I have two questions (Q1 and Q2), each has an answer encoded as integer (a question can have multiple answers, `Q2: 3, 4` means both 3 and 4 were chosen). Table might look like :

| ID | Q1 | Q2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | A |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | B |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | C |
| 4 | 1 | 3 & 4 | D |
| 5 | NOT 1 |  | E |
| ... | ... | ... | .... |

Where for the following answers I want to extract the following result :

- `Q1: 1`, `Q2: 1` -> `A` (rule ID 1)
- `Q1: 1`, `Q2: 2` -> `A` (rule ID 1)
- `Q1: 1`, `Q2: 3` -> `B` (rule ID 2)
- `Q1: 1`, `Q2: 4` -> `C` (rule ID 3)
- `Q1: 1`, `Q2: 3, 4` -> `D` (rule ID 4)
- `Q1: 2`, `Q2: 1` -> `E` (rule ID 5, Q2 can have any but also no value here)

Full dataset has 20-30 questions, but functionality is the same. How can I structure the dataset in an efficient and logical way? A long table might be more suitable, but I couldn't find a data structure / query combination that returns expected results.

One solution I don't find elegant as the data is wide (therefore I ask for a nicer solution) is to split the `OR` case into multiple rows, and concatenate the (sorted) digits of the `AND` case (see ID = 4 for Q2 = 34, which means both 3 and 4 must be selected to match). Additionally, for each question, two new variables are introduced: a negate (_neg) column if the result should be negated (no match) and an empty column if the result should be ignored as the field is left empty.

| id | q1 | q1_neg | q1_empty | q2 | q2_neg | q2_empty | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FALSE | FALSE | 1 | FALSE | FALSE | A |
| 1 | 1 | FALSE | FALSE | 2 | FALSE | FALSE | A |
| 2 | 1 | FALSE | FALSE | 3 | FALSE | FALSE | B |
| 3 | 1 | FALSE | FALSE | 4 | FALSE | FALSE | C |
| 4 | 1 | FALSE | FALSE | 34 | FALSE | FALSE | D |
| 5 | 1 | TRUE | FALSE |  | FALSE | TRUE | E |

For an answer with Q1 = 1 and Q2 = 4, query would look like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT result FROM example_table
WHERE 
  (q1_empty OR (q1 = 1 and NOT q1_neg) OR (q1 != 1 AND q1_neg)) AND -- for Q1 = 1
  (q2_empty OR (q2 = 4 and NOT q2_neg) OR (q2 != 4 AND q2_neg));    -- for Q2 = 4
```

Returns `C` (correct).

Table for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example_table (
    id integer,
    q1 integer,
    q1_neg boolean,
    q1_empty boolean,
    q2 integer,
    q2_neg boolean,
    q2_empty boolean,
    result char
);

INSERT INTO example_table(id, q1, q1_neg, q1_empty, q2, q2_neg, q2_empty, result) VALUES
 (1, 1, FALSE, FALSE, 1, FALSE, FALSE, 'A'),
 (1, 1, FALSE, FALSE, 2, FALSE, FALSE, 'A'),
 (2, 1, FALSE, FALSE, 3, FALSE, FALSE, 'B'),
 (3, 1, FALSE, FALSE, 4, FALSE, FALSE, 'C'),
 (4, 1, FALSE, FALSE, 34, FALSE, FALSE, 'D'),
 (5, 1,  TRUE, FALSE, 0 , FALSE, TRUE, 'E');
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `SELECT DISTINCT` will give you distinct _rows_. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT result FROM...` to make code clearer.

Comment: applied your comment - thanks!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms